# Download URL from Firestore Storage in wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, storage

i have a little problem with my Firebase-Storage.
In my storage I have some pictures like:

```
"apple.jpg", "blueberry.jpg", "melon.jpg"...
```

In my Swift-Code I have an Array with Fruit-Names like:

```
["Apple", "Blueberry", "Melon"]
```

In my function I loop through my Apple-Name-Array and if I print the fruitsRef I get the following result:

```
gs://myapp-5313d.appspot.com/sort/apple.jpg
gs://myapp-5313d.appspot.com/sort/blueberry.jpg
gs://myapp-5413d.appspot.com/sort/melon.jpg
```

but in my fruitsRef.downloadURL-Method I get random ordered results:

```
Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-5413d.appspot.com/o/sort%2Fblueberry.jpg?alt=media&token=5047d133-b37e-49d2-ae6c-59be5e7cafbf)

Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-5413d.appspot.com/o/sort%2Fmelon.jpg?alt=media&token=5047d133-b37e-49d2-ae6c-59be5e7cafbf)

Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-5413d.appspot.com/o/sort%2Fapple.jpg?alt=media&token=5047d133-b37e-49d2-ae6c-59be5e7cafbf)
```

```
func setUrlArray(sorts: Array<String>) {
  for currentSort in sorts {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let fruitsRef = storageRef.child("sort/" + currentSort.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") + ".jpg")
    print(fruitsRef)
    fruitsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
      print(url)
    }
  }
}
```

how is that possible?

kind regards,
doomsweb

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the asynchronous nature of the `downloadURL` function on your `fruitsRef` variable. When you are iterating the array, you are synchronously printing out the reference to the image (`print(fruitsRef)`), and then also kicking off an asynchronous task (`downloadURL`).

You've guaranteed that the `for` loop will print out the `fruitsRef` in a particular order, since you are looping through the array one at a time - however, you have no guarantees with regard to which order your Firebase storage will respond to your network requests.

From the server's perspective, you are asking for three different assets at basically the same time (since your app will loop through the array of three elements very quickly), and the server will try to respond to each request as soon as it's able. So as soon as any one of those assets is returned to your app, the `print(url)` line is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue now with a Little Trick. My fruits name Array was already sorted alphabetically. So I have sorted the array with the links now also alphabetically.  Now the order is correct